# Methods for applying is.infinite() to a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm wondering why I can't apply is.infinite() to a data frame in the same way I can apply is.na to a dataframe in R:

```
data[is.infinite(data)]<-0
Error in is.infinite(data) : 
  default method not implemented for type 'list'

data[is.na(data)] <-0
```

Produces no error, however, the documentation on is.infinite implies the same behavior as is.na?.

Does anyone know how I can replace inf values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one method, using `lapply` and `ifelse`:

```
# create data.frame
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10], c=rnorm(10))
df$a[c(2,6)] <- Inf
df$c[c(3,9)] <- Inf

# take care of those infs:
df[] <- lapply(df, function(i) if(is.numeric(i)) ifelse(is.infinite(i), 0, i) else i)
```

The problem I think is the x `is.infinite(x)` and `is.na(x)`. The help file for `?is.infinite` says

> `x` R object to be tested: the default methods handle atomic vectors

while for `?is.na`, it says

> `x` an R object to be tested: the default method for is.na handles atomic vectors, lists and pairlists: that for anyNA also handles NULL.

So the default method of `is.infinite` does not handle lists (data.frames) where are `is.na` does.

Answer (score 2):

As @Imo said correctly, `is.na()` has set up to work on lists/data.frames while `is.infinite()` can only work on vectors. You can work around this, however, by using `sapply()`:

```
df[sapply(df, simplify = 'matrix', is.infinite)] <- 0
```

This will select all cells in df that are infinite and insert "0" into them. The key is to use apply `is.infinite` to each column of the data frame, then have `sapply` simplify the result into a logical matrix which can be used to select cells. This is (I believe) basically what `is.na`is doing behind the scenes you apply it to a data frame.